# Traversal Error with custom view

Tags: plone, traversal

Working on a Plone 3.3.6 instance with a custom product that should display an flv type video. I'm trying to figure where to start in troubleshooting this traversalerror. I'm sure this was working on Plone 3.1.x (though I do have a good imagination).

```
TraversalError: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents')
```

I've included the traceback below:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 119, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 88, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 42, in call_object
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 770, in __call__
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 764, in render
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 129, in _exec
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 77, in PT_pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_utils, line 9, in call_pattern
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 98, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 117, in pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: exceptions.AttributeError: @@tag_macros
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 949, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 855, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 534, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 745, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 223, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: index
   - Line 128, Column 8
   - Expression: <StringExpr 'plone.belowcontentbody'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'context': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'default': <object object at 0xb7f33528>,
       'here': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xe3c866c>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://videoserver/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv/file_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <ImplicitAcquirerWrapper object at 0xe34dcec>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /data/Plone/buildout/eggs/p4a.video-1.3-py2.4.egg/p4a/video/browser/video.pt object at 0xe4ce36c>,
       'views': <zope.app.pagetemplate.viewpagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0xe2fa86c>}
  Module Products.Five.browser.providerexpression, line 37, in __call__
  Module plone.app.viewletmanager.manager, line 154, in render
  Module plone.app.viewletmanager.manager, line 83, in render
  Module plone.app.layout.viewlets.common, line 44, in render
  Module alteroo.assesscontent.browser.viewlet, line 95, in index
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 129, in _exec
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 77, in PT_pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_utils, line 9, in call_pattern
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 98, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 117, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 855, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 534, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 745, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 223, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: assessment_input
   - Line 12, Column 4
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:'view/contents'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'context': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'default': <object object at 0xb7f33528>,
       'here': <ATFile at /sites/videoserver/plone/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>,)},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xe15590c>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://videoserver/Members/johndoe/sample-video.flv/file_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <ImplicitAcquirerWrapper object at 0xe0dacec>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>,
       'views': <zope.app.pagetemplate.viewpagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0xe4bb78c>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 105, in trustedBoboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 164, in traversePathElement
   - __traceback_info__: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents')
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 52, in traverse
   - __traceback_info__: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents', [])
TraversalError: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents')
```

Further Information:
I pinned p4a.video to version 1.1, the buildout was pulling in 1.3. p4a.video was not compatible with older versions of hachoir packages, I needed at least the 1.2.1 packages before my instances would start properly. My versions section of my buildout configuration now includes the following.

**But it seems to be related to plone.app.z3cform**

```
extends =
        ...
        http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.z3cform/0.4.9?plone=3.3.6

[versions]
p4a.plonevideoembed = 1.1
p4a.video = 1.1
hachoir-core = 1.2.1
hachoir-metadata = 1.2.1
hachoir-parser = 1.2.1
```

How I've been going about this:

1. In general it has been very useful to launch my instance in foreground mode for troubleshooting (bin/instance fg).
2. http://good-py.appspot.com is an absolute life saver on this to pin versions (there was no option to pin for plone.app.z3cform 0.4.3, but 0.4.9 was close enough. As a result I still had to explicitly pin 0.4.3 in the [versions] section of my buildout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

The issue was related to a viewlet, associated with the view that I was trying to access.

The viewlet references a custom z3c.form in a template called 'assessment_input' hence this part of the traceback:

```
- URL: assessment_input
- Line 12, Column 4
```

I know this for sure because when I temporarily disabled the offending viewlet by commenting it out in the  browser/configure.zcml of my custom product the view began to work (without showing the viewlet of course).

The way that a z3c.form based form is rendered in plone changed in version 0.5.8 of plone.z3cform and greater(this is documented here: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10022), in versions of plone.z3cform prior to 0.5.8, it used to be possible to  render the form by calling "view/contents" in the viewlet template. The traceback implies that the newer plone.z3cform (which doesn't support the "view/contents" convention) was causing the error.

```
    - Expression: <PathExpr standard:'view/contents'>

    <snip> ...

      - __traceback_info__: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents', [])
   TraversalError: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.MyFormWrapper object at 0xe4c36cc>, 'contents')
```

The fix required that I pin my version of plone.z3cform to 0.5.7 in my buildout

```
[versions]
plone.z3cform = 0.5.7
```

As mentioned in the question I pinned the version of plone.app.z3cform 0.4.9 using a good-py known good set (KGS), I think this is necessary but haven't absolutely tested it.

This is a *good enough* solution for now, moving forward I will need to rewrite my viewlet for newer versions of my product so that when I upgrade to Plone 4.x the viewlet supports plone.z3cform's newer, and arguably better, approach of rendering the forms.